# How can I debug maxTicksLimits in charts.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using maxTicksLimits from charts.js seems to have no effect. There are no errors and my chart renders without error when reloading my page. Other options on ticks work without issue eg.`padding: 50` has the intended effect. Below is my code

```
var chartOptions = options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'please help me'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    padding: 50,
                    maxTicksLimits: 5,
                    autoSkip: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

I have tried using other options to debug and verify there isn't a problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the spelling `maxTicksLimits`

It should be used like shown in the below code, jsfiddle for your reference -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lhap6suy/

```
xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 2
        }
      }]
```